# Functional style counter in Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, closures

I am very new to functional programming concepts and was watching a presentation by Neil Ford in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeK979aqqqc). There he talks about a counter to demonstrate a piece of code without using a global state(at 20:04). Coming from Java world, I have some difficulty to understand the concept here and how the counter is incremented. Below is the relevant code

```
def makeCounter() {
    def very_local_variable = 0;
    return {very_local_variable += 1}
}

c1 = makeCounter()
c1()
c1()
c1()

c2 = makeCounter()
println "C1 = ${c1()}, C2 = ${c2()}"
```

He goes on to say that C1 = 4, and C2 = 1 will be printed. How does this happen? I am sure my lack of understanding here stems from probably a conceptual failure in how Groovy works or probably there is something general in functional languages like Groovy, Scala etc. Does a local variable within a method maintains its state until the function is called again and assigned to another variable? (A google search with "functional counter groovy| scala" brings nothing)

Comment: Read this: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures.

Comment: Especially the _"free variables"_ section

Comment: merci. I am enlightened now!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'd add that (plus a quoted snippet) as an answer :-)

Comment: true, i'd have chosen that as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why this question doesn't have an answer, but it probably deserves at least one for future visitors.

What you have written above is a simple example of [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). Closures are a language-agnostic idea, not tied to Groovy at all. You use them all the time e.g. in JavaScript.

A closure is essentially a *function or reference to a function together with a referencing environment*.

In your example each call to `makeCounter` introduces a new local `very_local_variable`, it's clear I think. What you do in the second line of that function is return a closure (`{ .. }` syntax) that takes no arguments and returns the local variable incremented by 1. The closure has access to that variable as long, as it exists (it's part of the *referencing environment*).

Each call to `makeCounter` creates a new local variable and returns a new closure, so each of them operates on its own local variable / environment.

Actually, if you come from Java island it shouldn't be that new to you. You have anonymous classes, which can access final variables, e.g.

```
Runnable makeCounter() {
  final int[] very_local_variable = {0};
  return new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          very_local_variable[0] += 1;
      }
  };
}


Runnable c1 = makeCounter();

c1.run();
c1.run();
c1.run();
```

Declaring the local variable as array, returning it as `Runnable` functor and so on.. it all comes from Java's design and limits, but in essence it's really close to your code. Java 8 bridges the gap even closer:

```
Runnable makeCounter() {
    int[] very_local_var = {0};
    return () -> { very_local_variable[0] += 1; };
}
```

Comment: I wanted to answer myself, but you were quicker :-).In the context of languages such as Groovy, Javascript etc,I understand how closures can be used this way. But in your Java ex., though I understand why we need Anon. class, final var., array etc., but how can we ever make use of the `very_local_variable` counter? I do use Anon. class and lambdas, but that is inorder to pass a behavior to a method along with data it has to manipulate. In-order to be of any use, I guess we have to modify it as `Runnable makeCounter(final int[] very_local_variable)` and pass it while calling `makeCounter()` or?

Comment: *but how can we ever make use of the `very_local_variable counter`* ... what do you mean? The same way you'd use a member of a class.. remember though, *Closures are poor man's objects and vice versa.* :-)